# Why is the religious name vs legal name question on hold

Tags: discussion

I think this question is a good fit [Short name vs legal name on resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/17725/7978)
There are going to be people with this problem at the workplace and this should be a valid question on the workplace stack. Why is this question put on hold ? Of course as a lot of answers, the answer to this question is going to be based on commonly accepted norms/opinions.

**EDIT** : I have made an attempt to edit the question and generalize it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to your great edit, it has been re-opened, and has a great answer to boot.

Keep up the good work!

(For those of you wondering what a good edit looks like, this is a great example -- he generalized the question to tackle the larger issue, removed details that are irrelevant to the larger question, and made it far easier to answer -- great job!)

Comment: it had that answer before the edit :-)

Comment: Apologies @Kate, didn't check the timestamps (both the edit and your answer said 10 hours ago at the time, woops?)

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the edit. The original question was much more interesting. It wasn't a question about a diminutive name vs full name or married name vs maiden name; but two wholly different names.

Comment: While the original question may be more interesting, the current question applies to more situations including the more specific one the person was asking about. That makes the current question, while more general, more accessible in the future and a better resource.

Comment: The edit made a completely different question. Using short name may be considered a whim, while by religious name it's not the case. The comments proove the people are confused about it.